# "um pequeno alto na brilha" slang, mis-spelling?

Tags: português-europeu

A person talking about discovering something on her body that turned out to be a cancer said, "Olhe apareceu-me um pequeno alto na brilha ,eu fui ao médico pensando que fosse uma herne"
It would seem to say, a small? (un-named thing) above the 'shining'
Because she often make errors in her writing she may have mis-spelled one of the the words, especially "brilha". Or it is slang for an embarrassing body part. She though it was a hernia, which indicates lower abdomen. Could someone tell me what she means and what it would seem she found.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's a simple case of "betacism", [**loss of distinction between the sounds of b and v in a language or dialect**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/betacism). Your friend probably meant "virilha" instead of "birilha" which, in pt-PT would be pronounced as "b'rilha"

Acredito tratar-se de um **betacismo**.  "apareceu-me um pequeno alto **na virilha** e fui ao médico pensando trata-se de uma **hérnia**".  Nesse caso, talvez quem escreveu seja um minhoto, que frequentemente troca e pronuncia o "v" como se fosse um "b".

> - [**betacismo**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betacismo), vulgarmente referido em Portugal como trocar os "v" pelos "b" é o fenômeno linguístico que consiste na troca da pronúncia dos sons v por b. Ocorre em especial nas línguas românicas, como castelhano, galego, catalão, occitano, língua sarda, **dialetos do norte de Portugal** e alguns dialetos do sul da Itália. É um dos fenômenos da evolução fonética mais comum, identificado pela linguística histórica independentemente da genealogia linguística.

Exemplos do betacismo na Língua Portuguesa:

- assovio – assobio;
- vassoura – bassoura;
- travesseiro – trabesseiro;
- suvaco – subaco;
- veterano – beterano;
- vaca - baca

Comment: Thanks very much. I have no doubt that betacism was the problem. She often writes as she would speak, and since my Portuguese is quite poor, I am often confused. And certainly Google translate can't handle that sort of thing. Thanks again,